# Get a User Object by username field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I've looked around and cannot figure out how to get a different user by their user name, something tells me this is not possible am I correct? I want the user to be capable of using Game Center or Google Play and not just Facebook as an id. That means I can register anyone I want as a user and then find their friends (without having to use FB). Should I just make a separate Table to store this info?

I have attached code below for what should work, can anyone give some insight in either my code or on why I cannot get "bob". I have tested this code against another table and I can get the rows.

The code falls through properly and I do get to the foreach but there are no results to iterate through

I have also tried "_User" but get

> ArgumentException: Use the class-specific query properties for class _User
>   Parameter name: className

Any help here would be great I would like to avoid making another Table just for searching and doing relationships to other tables.

```
private void getParseObjectTest()
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("User").WhereEqualTo("username", "bob");
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(user =>
    {
        if (user.IsCanceled || user.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Can't get the user.... " + user.Exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Return was success time to iterate");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = user.Result;
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                string str = result.Get<string>("email");
                Debug.Log("email: " + str);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity you must use ParseUser.Query instead of ParseObject.Query when querying users.

https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#users-querying

Answer (score 1):

And if you can't do what wbdev said (because there is another bug triggered by using generic ParseQuery objects), you can create the non-generic query with `new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("_User")`.